# I am trying to retrieve data from a database using ajax and populate in form that is in a bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need a help here when I click on the edit button on the image below i expect to see data populated on a form in a bootstrap modal window I am using jquery ajax method to populate the data in the form of
[image: My home page]

and the edit modal image
[image]

Here is code for the home page

```html
 <?php require_once("connect.php"); ?>
 <?php require_once("fetch.php"); ?>
 <?php require_once("select.php"); ?>
 <?php require_once("process.php"); ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>Home</title>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  
     <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
     <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
       <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       </ul>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add</button>
       <table class="table" id="table">
        <tr>
         <th>S/N</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Edit</th>
         <th>View</th>
         <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
         $query = "SELECT * FROM contact";
         $runQuery = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
         if(!$runQuery){
          die("Could not run select query ".mysqli_error($connect));
         }
         $sn = 1;
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runQuery)){  ?> 
      <tr>
       <td><?php echo $sn++  ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row["name"]  ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row["email"]  ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row["description"]  ?></td>
       <td>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit-data" id="<?php echo $row['userid']  ?>">Edit</button>
       </td>
       <td>
        <button type="button" data-target="#viewModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm view-data" id="<?php echo $row['userid']  ?>">View</button>
       </td>
       <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm del-data" id="<?php echo $row['userid']  ?>">Danger</button>
       </td>
      </tr>
        <?php } ?>
       </table>
       <!-- Modal -->
       <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
         <div class="modal-dialog">

           <!-- Modal content-->
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">Add Data</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
              <div id="success" class="alert alert-success"></div>
               <form class="form" method="POST" id="insertData">
                <div id="nameError" class="alert alert-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Name</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
                </div>
                <div id="emailError" class="alert alert-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Email</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="userid" id="contactUserId">
                <div id="descriptionError" class="alert alert-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Description</label>
                 <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>       
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" name="add" id="add">
               </form>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
           </div>

         </div>
       </div>
       <div id="viewModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
         <div class="modal-dialog">

           <!-- Modal content-->
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">View Data</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body" id="contactDetail">
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
           </div>

         </div>
       </div>
       
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
     

     <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

This code is for entering  and updating data in the database process.php

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST)){

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $userid = $_POST["userid"];

    if($userid != ''){
        $query = "UPDATE contact SET name = '$name', email='$email', description='$description' WHERE userid = $userid ";
        $runQuery = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        if(!$runQuery){
            die("Could not run query ".mysqli_error($connect));
        }
    }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO contact(name, email, description) VALUES ";
        $query .=" ('$name', '$email', '$description')";
        $runQuery = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        if(!$runQuery){
            die("Could not run insert query ".mysqli_error($connect));
        }
    }
}
```

This code retrieves data from database

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['userid'])){
    $editId = (int)$_POST['userid'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE userid = $editId";
    $runQuery = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if(!$runQuery){
        die("Could not run query ".mysqli_error($connect));
    }
    $getData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runQuery);
    echo json_encode($getData);

}
```

This is my js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#insertData").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($("#name").val() == ""){
        $("#nameError").css("display", "block").html("Name is required");
    }else if ($("#email").val() == "") {
        $("#emailError").css("display", "block").html("Email is required");
    }else if ($("#description").val() == "") {
        $("#descriptionError").css("display", "block").html("Description is required");
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: $("#insertData").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $("#success").css("display", "block").html("Data added");
                $("#insertData")[0].reset();
            }
        });
    }

});

$(document).on("click", ".edit-data", function(){
    var contactId = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url:"index.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {contactId:contactId},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $("#name").val(data.name);
            $("#email").val(data.email);
            $("#description").val(data.description);
            $("#contactUserId").val(data.userid);
            $("#add").val("Update");
            $("#myModal").modal("show");

        }

    });

});

$(document).on('click', '.view-data', function(){  
          var contactId = $(this).attr("id");  
          if(contactId != '')  
          {  
               $.ajax({  
                    url:"index.php",  
                    method:"POST",  
                    data:{contactId:contactId},  
                    success:function(data){  
                         $('#contactDetail').html(data);  
                         $('#viewModal').modal('show');  
                    }  
               });  
          }            
     });
```

});

Comment: The way you tried is very messy,IMO. you just have to do this. HTML/CSS is okay. on click of edit button, you can show the modal window and make ajax call, which will read the db, then return the data. then you can use jquery to set each value to it's respective field

Comment: You are encoding the data, but i couldn't find anywhere decoding it. In the ajax success, "data = JSON.parse(data);" put this as your first line and then try it.It may solve your problem.

Comment: @Vishwa thanks for your effort, I will appreciate if you show me a code snippet for it

Comment: @Rishi thank you so much for replying I tried it but still did not work, I am trying to replicate what I learned from a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpyVEbFQ6Bc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: can you also shortened your code and paste only the part that doesn't work.

Comment: @JuniusL. Thanks, I think the whole thing is needed so someone can trace where the error is coming from as Rishi pointed out.

Comment: @Benedict See in 'Network' tab whether your request is fetching results or not.Tell us more about the error coming in console or network tab

Comment: @Rishi everything is fine on the nework and console tab

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `contactId` and in your PHP you are looking for `userid`. Change your data to `data: { userid: userid }`.

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit-data", function() {

    var userid = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
      url: "index.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: { userid: userid },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#name").val(data.name);
        $("#email").val(data.email);
        $("#description").val(data.description);
        $("#contactUserId").val(data.userid);
        $("#add").val("Update");
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply it still did not work I think the problem is coming from data: {contactId : contactId} I am yet to understand this concept.

Comment: Yes change `data: {contactId : contactId}` to `data: { userid: userid }` like I said, because your PHP is looking for `$_POST['userid'])` and you are sending `contactId`

Comment: and also make sure that, `index.php` doesn't contain html code.